# How to enable 32 bit .Net app to run in Windows 2012 R2 64bit

Tags: .net, windows, 64-bit

i wonder if any way to run Windows .Net 32 bit app, NOT ASP.NET, to run in Windows 2012 R2 server.

I have compiled the app with a Windows 32bit, with .Net version 2.0.
But when I copy the exe to the server I get an error that vjslib.dll is not found,
an unhandledException: Syste.IO.FileNotFoundException.

But I find the files under Framework\2.0.xxx folder.

In asp.net you have to specific enabled 32 bit applications.
Is there any setting to run some specific exe with specific .net clr ?

Best Regards

Comment: Check if you have compiled your application for x86 cpu mode.

Comment: Another possibility is the version of vsjlib.dll found on the server machine. There is a 64bit version and of course this will not be seen by a 32bit app. Here the download for both kind of vsjlib.dll https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/vstudio/bb188593

Answer (score 0):

Latest Windows releases do not ship WOW64 components which enables 32 bit apps to run on 64 bit Windows.

You can manually enable this feature via Server Manager, and then try again, but it is highly recommended to build 64 bit apps these days.